# Run SSMS from the remote server with difference windows domain and user

Tags: sql-server

I have installed SQL Server 2017 (64bit) in server A. I have chose windows authentication during the installation, and added windows account DomainA\User1.

Now I want to connect to db from remote server (with account is DomainB\User2). I tried with below command:

> **runas** /netonly /user:**DomainA\User1** "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"

Then enter the password of DomainA\User1, but at the login window, SSMS still show the current window account DomainB\User2

Is there any wrong with this approach to access to database remotely?

Answer (score 0):

Following must work:

```
runas /user:DomainA\User1 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"
```

`/netonly` Indicates that the user information specified is for remote access only. but in your case not just the access complete application (ssms.exe) must run on specified user. [source..](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771525(v%3Dws.11)#parameters)

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have tried to access to DB remotely by SSMS with difference window domain and account. Also tried with your advice but met error: "RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe
1: Incorrect function."